# How to serialize/deserialize (JSON) ArrayLIst<A> which has an ArrayLIst<B> as field in Java

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, arraylist

I'm new in Android programming's world and I've some problems using JSON to serialize and deserialize an ArrayList of custom objects. I know how to serialize an object, but not if it has an ArrayList as a field.

I found the GSON library but I don't really know how to use it.

I have an ArrayList of a **class A** which has an ArrayList of a **class B**. I'm serializing class A using a **toJSON()** method:

```
public class A
{
     //Some fields like title, id...
     private String mTitle;
     private ArrayList<B> mArray; //I don't know how to serialize/deserialize this field

     public A(){...}
     public A(JSONObject json){...}

     public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException //method I use to convert my object into a JSONObject
     {
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
          json.put("TITLE",mTitle);

          return json;
     }
}

public class B
{
     //some fields like a double, String...
     public B(){...}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of collection, you must specify the type.

[See a Guide User](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

In your case, I think this will solve:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<A>>(){}.getType();
Collection<A> list = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Where `A` is your class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is a Collection like an ArrayLIst ? Because I need to use ArrayList (to display in a ListView). Can I use this with ArrayList even if my class A doesn't have a method to transform its ArrayList of B in JSONObject ?

Comment: Yes. [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) is a java interface implemented for ArrayList, HashMap, etc, so you can, in you case, do that for example: `ArrayList<A> myArray = (ArrayList)list;` without problem. I Think you will don't no more need define types.

Comment: Ok, I see what is it, but I don't really understand how Java knows how to "convert" all B objects in my ArrayList to JSONObject using Collection and to store them in an other JSONObject.

Comment: You wonder how it's done? If so, GSON use [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) for access methods and proprieties from classes in runtime.

Comment: Ah ok, so I don't need to implement anything else than a Gson object to serialize and deserialize ? Because I tried to serialize my object and it has failed. Do you have a concrete code about how to implement it in code because that's totally new for me and I don't know a lot about Collection etc...

Comment: I've understood ! Your code works great thanks ! It's really easy to use in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Parcelable? Try something like this (pseudo code):

```
public class ParcelableObject implements Parcelable{

List<ObjectB> _customObjectList = new ArrayList<ObjectB>();

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel outParcel_, int arg1) {
outParcel_.writeTypedList(_customObjectList); //where _customObjectList is your list variable
}


//Then in your constructor which takes in a Parcel:

public ParcelableObject(Parcel parcelIn_) {
parcelIn_.readTypedList(_customObjectList, ObjectB.CREATOR);
}

}
```

ObjectB

```
public class ObjectB implements Parcelable{

int _randomInt;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ObjectB> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ObjectB>() {
        @Override
        public ObjectBcreateFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ObjectB(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ObjectB[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ObjectB[size];
        }
    };

    public ObjectB(Parcel parcelIn_) {
          _randomInt = parcelIn_.readInt();

    }



    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out_, int flags) {
        out_.writeInt(_randomInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using Parcelable, because I need JSONObject, to have .json files.

Comment: @gallium why not try this then, write a POJO that will encapsulate the JSON data into something meaningful. Like for example, if your JSON object contained data about people, then you would make a POJO that would have fields and getter/setter for your Person object. Then, you can implement Parcelable and do something like I've described. That way, you have a standard interface for your objects and can be used more easily than just raw JSON data.

Comment: I don't know if it is what about you're speaking, but I have a class named ClientCenter which is static and which contains my data: ArrayList of Client class (A). And the Client Class has a field which is an ArrayList of Class Debt (B). I was wondering how to use simple serializer because i'm learning Android progamming with [this book](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/android_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide) and they don't use Parcelable or Gson but they don't explain how to serialize an object with an custom object as field...

Answer (score 0):

What is better is to do something like that:

```
List<YourObject> myList = new Genson().deserialize(dta.toString(), List.class);
```